# What is the simplest procedure for compiling Asymptote code in WinEdt?

Tags: compiling, winedt, asymptote

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX document containg Asymptote code in WinEdt and my MWE is this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}[width=10cm,height=10cm]
import graph3;

size3(200);
currentprojection=orthographic(3,3,2);
currentlight=light(8,10,2);

int k1, k2, n = 5;
real alpha = 0.3*pi;

// cross section of the quintic 6D Calabi-Yau manifold
triple cy(pair z) {

  pair z1, z2;

  if(z==(0,0)) {
    z1 = exp(2*pi*I*k1/n);
    z2 = 0;
  } else {
    z1 = exp(2*pi*I*k1/n)*exp(log(cos(I*z))*2/n);
    z2 = exp(2*pi*I*k2/n)*exp(log(-I*sin(I*z))*2/n);
  }

  return (z2.x, cos(alpha)*z1.y + sin(alpha)*z2.y, z1.x);

}

for(k1=0; k1<n; ++k1) {
  for(k2=0; k2<n; ++k2) {
    surface s = surface(cy,(-1,0),(1,0.5*pi),20,20);
    draw(s,yellow+orange);
  }
}

\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Example above from [calabi with Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143123/how-to-draw-the-logo-of-the-string-theory/144489#144489)

The procedure I follow to compile it in WinEdt is:

1. latex main
2. Click icon "Asymptote" to use Asymptote add-on in WinEdt.
3. latex main.
4. Click icon "dvi-ps" in WinEdt.
5. Click icon "ps-pdf" in WinEdt.

and I get a document with extension `.pdf` like this

[image: iooo]

My question is: **is there a simpler procedure for compiling Asymptote code in WinEdt?**

Comment: I am not used with Windows. If you want to create a pdf file, it is better to use pdflatex. So the method is 1) pdflatex compilation 2) asymptote compilation 3) pdflatex compilation (twice for reference, bibliography, etc). Do not forget that you have the choice to include asymptote figures in your latex file through asy environment or to create a sample and separate asymptote figure (name_of_your_figure.asy) (and then include it with \includegraphics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just made some improvements to the Asymptote add-on for WinEdt.

You can find the latest version (just uploaded) at http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Asymptote.html. Simply install it over the old one.

Now, what you have to do to have the above code fully compiled and have the final `.pdf` file, is to click on the "PDFTeXify" button in the toolbar

[image]

or press the corresponding shortcut: <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+P</kbd>.

Comment: @kalkoeller, one question again, how to remove black line at the result .pdf file ?

Comment: @karkoeller, Asymptote add ons is not full compiled the result .pdf , there is file Asymptote is not appear,  for more information from this : http://l-hirwanto.blogspot.com/2015/01/asymptote-add-ons-is-not-full-compiled.html

Comment: @Hirwanto It works fine for me and I don't get any black line. Also compiling `latexusage.tex` (the file you are showing in your blog) everything is fine on my side.

Comment: @Hirwanto BTW: to compile with latex there is a button in the dropdown button PDFTeXify. No need to manually do it at the command line.

Comment: sorry for that. On my opinion, maybe error at my sistems.

Comment: @Hirwanto No need to be sorry. If you don't get the same result update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20071/discussion-between-hirwanto-and-karlkoeller).

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks again for your great WinEdt's add-ons!

Comment: @Sterry Not at all :-)

Comment: Black lines are due to some OpenGL driver problems. See the documentation http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/three.html#three and the `-glOptions=-indirect` option.